# Spring boot project on Heroku unable to use application.yml

Tags: java, spring, heroku, spring-boot

As the title states I'm trying to deploy a spring boot application to heroku.

Under /resources I have an application.yml file from which I inject properties using @Value annotation.

During boot I get a stacktrace but I believe the relevant part is the below

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dk.fitfit.remotetexting.util.GoogleAuth dk.fitfit.remotetexting.api.controller.MessageController.googleAuth; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'googleAuth': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dk.fitfit.remotetexting.business.service.ConfigurationService dk.fitfit.remotetexting.util.GoogleAuth.configurationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String dk.fitfit.remotetexting.business.service.ConfigurationService.clientId; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'security.oauth2.client.clientId' in string value "${security.oauth2.client.clientId}"
```

Basically it says it can't create my ConfigurationService because it can't resolve my placeholder 'security.oauth2.client.clientId'.

```
@Service
public class ConfigurationService {
    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${fcm.auth_key}")
    private String AUTH_KEY_FCM;

    @Value("${fcm.api_url}")
    private String API_URL_FCM;
    ...
}
```

Any clues about how to make heroku use my application.yml file?

Comment: How are you running the app locally? Do you use a command like `java -jar myapp.jar` or a mvn/gradle command?

Comment: I use either "mvn spring-boot:run" or "mvn -B -DskipTests clean dependency:list install" which I can see that heroku also do.

Comment: Try running locally with a `java -jar` command (like the one you see when you run `heroku ps`). I suspect you will be able to reproduce the problem, which is that the `application.yml` is not on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to include application.yml file in my repository... doh!